# WebView costs some time to show GIF images in Android

Tags: android, webview, gif

I use following code to display a loader GIF image on app start up:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.loading_gif);
String data = "<body style='background:transparent;padding:0'>" + "<img src=\"loadinfo_24.gif\"/></body>";
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data , "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

The gif shows, but with obvious latency (in a couple of seconds and the period varies time by time).

How can I make it show immediately?

(I know there are other manners to show GIF such as movie view or image decoder, but WebView is the simplest in my opinion.)

Comment: Use a better solution than an animated GIF, such as an `AnimationDrawable`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/01/converting-animated-gifs-animationdrawables.html

Comment: @CommonsWare data is coming from webview, you are suggesting to convert whole webview into layout.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: "data is coming from webview" -- no, the animated GIF is coming from assets. "you are suggesting to convert whole webview into layout" -- I am suggesting to replace the animated GIF with a better solution, such as an `AnimationDrawable`.

Comment: String contains full html "<body style='background:transparent;padding:0'>" + "<img src=\"loadinfo_24.gif\"/></body>", probably there will be more in future.

Comment: btw your solution is good if there is only one image